# MATLAB: VideoReader error checking

Tags: matlab, error-handling, crash, video-processing, avi

I'm doing some image processing on several thousand small .avi files. A small subset of the files appear to be damaged.

One type of damage seems to be a particular frame of the video that can't be read in. I added a try-catch block for this and it works well.

Another type of damage, however, is, according to VLC, "Broken or missing AVI Index". When VideoReader attempts to open files with this type of damage it crashes Matlab completely with the error, "MATLAB has encountered an internal problem and needs to close." And details message, "Segmentation violation detected at Wed Apr ..."

So my question is, is there any way to error check/skip videos that would cause this crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) for checking the integrity of video file.

See: [How can I check the integrity of a video file (avi, mpeg, mp4…)?](https://superuser.com/questions/100288/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-video-file-avi-mpeg-mp4)
Download static build of `ffmpeg`, and put `ffmpeg.exe` in your working directory.

Execute `ffmpeg` within Matlab using `system` command, and check the return status.
If status is not zero, the video file is corrupted.
You may also parse the output error message for finer logic.

Here is a code sample:

```
filename = 'input.avi';

if (isunix)
    [status, cmdout] = system(['ffmpeg.exe -v error -i ', filename, ' -f null - 2']);
else
    [status, cmdout] = system(['ffmpeg.exe -v error -i ', filename, ' -f null - 2>&1']);
end

if (status ~= 0)
   %Dispaly cmdout if file is damaged.
   disp([filename, ' is corrupted.  Error: ', cmdout]);
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm running into an issue, this seems to work for error checking some broken indexes, but passes as if they were good videos on others. I'm not sure what the difference is between two videos both which say broken index but produce two different outputs. Any idea?

Comment: It's hard to tell without a sample file... Are you using Windows or Linux? You can try executing `ffprobe` tool (downloaded with `ffmpeg`). Try searching for AVI specific format analyzing tools. AVI video files are playable without an index (just become unseekable). You can try fixing the files, I found `DivFix++` using Google (never used it).